# React hook array to a specific format to be used in react native Calendar

Tags: react-hooks

I have date value in this format from a for each loop. Each loop provides value in the following format.

start: 2021-06-30T18:30:00.000Z
title: one

start: 2021-07-31T18:30:00.000Z
title: two

start: 2021-08-31T18:30:00.000Z
title: three

```
function loadItems() {
    firebase.database().ref("events").once("value", (userSnapshot) => {
      
      userSnapshot.forEach(element => {
        const start = moment(element.child('start').val()).toDate();
        const title = element.child('title').val();
      )}
   )}
}
```

I have created variables like this.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState([]);
```

I need to convert this to the following format. How can I use useState to update the value on for each loop.

```
markedDates={{
    '2021-06-30': {selected: true, marked: true},
    '2021-06-30': {selected: true, marked: true},
    '2021-06-30': {selected: true, marked: true},
  }}

items={{
    '2021-06-30': [{name: 'one'}],
    '2021-06-30': [{name: 'two'}],
    '2021-06-30': [{name: 'three'}],
    
  }}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you need to "convert". Where the data comes from? Is a json? "I have date value in this format from a for each loop" Where is that for each loop? You question is confusing

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I have updated my question. I get the data from firebase. I have to create markedDates and items from the firebase data to populate events in React native calendar

Comment: your items has object with same key '2021-06-30'.. You need to push data to the same key like '2021-06-30': [{}, {}, {}]. Use array.reduce method to write the logic

Comment: Based on the above question it is apparent that the key are same. But I receive different keys from the firebase. Anyway the reduce method was so helpful and I have resolved using the same. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce your firebase array to required format. Something along these lines would do the job.

```
const items = userSnapshot.reduce((accumulator: any, item: any) => {
    
  if(accumulator.hasOwnProperty(item.start.slice(0, 10))) {
    accumulator = {...accumulator, [item.start.slice(0, 10)]: [...accumulator[item.start.slice(0, 10)], { name: item.title }]}
  } else {
    accumulator = {...accumulator, [`${item.start.slice(0, 10)}`]: [{ name: item.title }]}
  }

  return accumulator
}, {})
```